# Do I have to add owner's of images if they also belong to me?

Tags: copyright

Let's suppose I am running a car shop where I import cars from a manufacturer. On my website, I will put some images of the cars I sell. If these images belong to the manufacturer, **but I have those types of cars**, do I have to state that they belong to the manufacturer? If I don't do so, am I violating the copyrights?

Comment: You're violating copyright even if you give credit, because those photos are not yours. Unless you obtain permission but this will include what if any credit you must give.

Comment: If you already own those cars, why not just take your own photos of the cars that you own? Then the photos will belong to you. Someone else's photo of the same model of car does not belong to you just because you have the same or the same model of the subject of the photograph. If you make your own photos this will also make your advertising will be more trustworthy because the customers will see the photos are actually of the cars that you have, and not just copy/pastes from a different web site.

Comment: I am just too lazy to edit the photos I take :) Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot legally post those images at all, with or without credit, unless you have some form of permission from the copyright holder. In this case the manufacturer is probably the rights holder, but it might be some person or firm who created the images under contract to the  manufacturer.

If you have permission, perhaps as part of your contract with the manufacturer, then that permission may well specify whether and how the images must be credited.  Such restrictions, if present in whatever license you have been granted, must be adhered to.

As Brandin commented, you are perfectly safe if you take your own photos of the cars you own and post those, or hire someone to do so for you. Or else you must ask the owner(s) of the photos you want to use for permission, and get it, before posting them.